# Parse movie text data into a dataframe

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have some .txt data from a movie script that looks like this.

```
                              JOHN
                   Hi man. How are you?

                              TOM
                   A little hungry but okay.

                              JOHN
                   Let's get breakfast then
```

I'd like to parse out the text and create a dataframe with 2 columns. I for person e.g JOHN and TOM and a second column for the lines (which are the block of text below each name). The result would be like..

index | person | lines

0 | JOHN   | "Hi man. How are you?"

1 | TOM    | "A little hungry but okay."

2 | JOHN   | "Let's get breakfast then"

Comment: You've provided a good description of the problem and some test data, but no attempt at a solution. How do you think you would need to go about reading a text file, breaking it up into regular pieces and putting the data in a DataFrame? (those three tasks are all more or less trivial, but perhaps you're having a *specific* issue?)

Comment: `split('\n)` (on newlines) might return a list that has the character's name in the first element of each list

Comment: you have empty lines then you can use `split('\n\n")` with double `\n` to split in list of strings `["JOHN\nHi man. How are you?", "TOM\nA little hungry but okay."]`. And later every string you can `split('\n', 1)` to get list  `["JOHN", "Hi man. How are you?"]`

Comment: if every text is in one line then you can use `split("\n")` to split to lines

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If every text is in one line then you can split to lines

```
 lines = text.split('\n')
```

Remove spaces

```
 lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]
```

And use slice `[start:end:step]` to create dataframe

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': lines[0::3],
    'lines':  lines[1::3]
})
```

---

Example:

```
text = '''                            JOHN
                   Hi man. How are you?

                              TOM
                   A little hungry but okay.

                              JOHN
                   Let's get breakfast then'''

lines = text.split('\n')
lines = [x.strip() for x in lines]

import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'person': lines[0::3],
    'lines': lines[1::3]
})

print(df)
```

Result:

```
  person                      lines
0   JOHN       Hi man. How are you?
1    TOM  A little hungry but okay.
2   JOHN   Let's get breakfast then
```

---

If person may have text in many lines - ie.

```
                        JOHN
                   Hi man.
                   How are you?
```

then it needs more spliting and striping.

You can do it before creating DataFrame.

```
text = '''                            JOHN
                   Hi man.
                   How are you?

                              TOM
                   A little hungry but okay.

                              JOHN
                   Let's get breakfast then'''

data = []

parts = text.split('\n\n')
for part in parts:
    person, lines = part.split('\n', 1)
    person = person.strip()
    lines = "\n".join(x.strip() for x in lines.split('\n'))
    data.append([person, lines])

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.columns = ['person', 'lines']

print(df)
```

Or you can try to do it after creating DataFrame

```
text = '''                            JOHN
                   Hi man.
                   How are you?

                              TOM
                   A little hungry but okay.

                              JOHN
                   Let's get breakfast then'''

lines = text.split('\n\n')
lines = [x.split('\n', 1) for x in lines]

import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(lines)
df.columns = ['person', 'lines']

df['person'] = df['person'].str.strip()
df['lines'] = df['lines'].apply(lambda txt: "\n".join(x.strip() for x in txt.split('\n')))

print(df)
```

Resulst:

```
  person                      lines
0   JOHN      Hi man.\nHow are you?
1    TOM  A little hungry but okay.
2   JOHN   Let's get breakfast then
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked. I had figured out the strip and split parts but didnt know about [start:end:step] for dataframe creation

Answer (score 1):

I know I'm late to this party but this will parse an entire script into a dictionary of character name and their dialogue as values all you need to do then is `df = pd.DataFrame(final_dict.values(), columns = final_dict.keys())`

```
*# Grouped regex pattern to capture char and dialouge in a tuple
char_dialogue = re.compile(r"(?m)^\s*\b([A-Z]+)\b\s*\n(.*(?:\n.+)*)")
extract_dialogue = char_dialogue.findall(script)

final_dict = {}

for element in extract_dialogue:
   # Seperating the character and dialogue from the tuple
   char = element[0]
   line = element[1]
   # If the char is already a key in the dictionary
   # and line is not empty append the dialogue to the value list
   if char in final_dict:
       if line != '':
           final_dict[char].append(line)
   else:
       # Else add the character name to the dictionary keys with their first line
       # Drop any lower case matches from group 0
       # Can adjust the len here if you have characters with fewer letters
       if char.isupper() and len(char) >2:
           final_dict[char] = [line]

        
# Some final cleaning to drop empty dalouge 

final_dict = {k: v for k, v in final_dict.items() if v  != ['']}

# More filtering to reutrn only main characters with more than 50 
# lines of dialogue 

final_dict = {k: v for k, v in final_dict.items() if len(v) > 50}*
```